# waitFor() doesn't find element which is displayed on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am trying to run my first code on puppeteer.

Puppeteer **v1.20.0**

Node **v8.11.3**

Npm **v5.6.0**

It is a basic example but it doesn't works :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/learning/login', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

  console.log(0);
  await page.waitFor('#username');
  console.log(1);

  await browser.close();
});
```

When I run the script, chromium start and I can see the Linkedin login page with the form and the #username form's field, but puppeteer doesn't find the field. It displays `0` but never `1` and then runs a `TimeoutError: waiting for selector "#username" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded`.

Increase timeout doesn't change anything and if I check the console in chromium the field is there.

Linkedin login page works as an SPA and I don't know if I'm using the right way here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [I'm also getting `null`](https://i.imgur.com/F16p7Ti.png). The correct selector seems to be `'.sign-in-form__inputs input[name=session_key]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

username input is inside iframe you cant access it like this , you need to access iframe first

```
    await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/learning/login');
    await page.waitForSelector('.authentication-iframe');

    var frames = await page.frames();
    var myframe = frames.find(
        f =>
            f.url().indexOf("uas/login") > 0);

    let username = '123456@gmail.com';
    const usernamefild = await myframe.$("#username");
    await usernamefild.type(username, {delay: 10});
```

Comment: I checked in dev tools but didn't see the frame. Thank you :)
I then tried to type `await login_iframe.type('#username', email, {delay: 100});` or `const username = await login_iframe.$("#username"); await username.type(email, {delay: 100});` but didn't work with the value `123456@gmail.com` but worked for value `test@gmail.com` or `123456`, strange. I fix it with `await login_iframe.evaluate((text) => { (document.getElementById('username')).value = text; }, email);`. You know why ?

Comment: @ElJackiste `123456@gmail.com` works for me ... do you get an error or it doesn't type at all ? i've updated my code a bit ... try my code and see

Comment: Still the same problem for me with your new code. Only the first letter is typed inside the field. If i just fill the password field, it is the same problem... Found the solution describe above (getElementById) with this link : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1648